# How to return Distinct value from this sql table? Where the id gots duplicated but picture is unique

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have post table which is joined with picture table.

Because 1 post have multiple images basically join makes post data duplicated with just unique image;

In this table some of ID`s are getting repeated multiple times (only image url is unique).

I need to return some data without repeated id's. Meaning that if there are three of 187, I should get back just first 187 with all rows and data.

I tried

```
SELECT  
    items.id, user_name, user_phone, user_avatar, item_category, 
    item_title, item_price, item_description, item_location, 
    item_lat, item_lng, images.image_url
FROM 
    users 
INNER JOIN 
    items ON users.id = items.user_id 
INNER JOIN 
    images ON images.post_id = items.id
WHERE 
    DISTINCT items.id
```

But it throws an error:

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per `items.id`, then you can use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (i.id) i.id, user_name, user_phone, user_avatar,
       item_category, item_title, item_price, item_description,
       item_location, item_lat, item_lng, im.image_url
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     items i
     ON u.id = i.user_id INNER JOIN
     images im
     ON im.post_id = i.id
ORDER BY i.id;
```